Meaning of なっ as an interjection?
I've stumbled on to what I think is an interjection in the following sentence:
ああ ペス！ペス！　なっ おまえも　外の世界に出たいだろ？
(Note: ペス is a dog)
What exactly is なっ supposed to mean here?

It's an interjectory particle な used to seek agreement or confirmation. Depending on what has been said before this, it's used to add the nuance of "come on, don't you think so?", "I told you", or "I was right, huh?" to the sentence.
